# Bounties not displayed on the home tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

The home tab http://www.stackoverflow.com/ displays that there are zero bounties on the entire site

[image]

The bounties are only shown when the url is http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/*

For example the following pages *do* show the number of bounties:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/active
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift

but http://www.stackoverflow.com/ does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in builds `3790` (meta) and `2910` (main).